# Flashdrive loaded with Ubuntu 20 crashed my laptop with Microsoft 10

Tags: boot

I wanted to try Ubuntu 20 on my new laptop with Windows 10 but when I booted with the flash drive loaded with Ubuntu 20 courtesy of Rufus the download only got as far as the page asking me to choose the try out icon or the full installation and then froze and crashed the computer.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: It usually does not do this, unless there is a driver missing for your hardware.  Usually brand new hardware that just came out.  Can add specs for your hardware to your question and change Ubuntu 20 to Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10(or correct version you have) so we can help better.  Can also just be the ISO was not burn correctly to USB or bad ISO download.

Comment: Hi, my computer is a new Microsoft Surface Laptop3 and I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.1 desktop amd 64 into the download file before putting it onto the USB stick as an ISO file. Booting up from the USB seems to go

Comment: Know that some Surface laptops can be very difficult to have everything work with Ubuntu.  Would do google search containing install ubuntu on laptop.  Replace laptop with exact make and model.  (Surface 3 plus model xxxx).  Might have to try another type of Linux to work.  There is one that starts with 'G' that seems to work when nothing else does on surface laptops.

Comment: Hi, OK will do as you suggest. Many thanks.